# How do I avoid datagridrow highlight function bombing out on Null?

Tags: datagridview, nullreferenceexception, highlight

I have a function whcih is designed to highlight rows where certain cells don't match each other. This works until it hits a cell which contains nothing, then it bombs out as a nullrefexception. I know I'm missing something simple here but I'm banging my head against a wall trying to figure it out!
Thanks in advance.

```
        private void highlightrow()
    {
        int rowcnt = 0;
        dataGridView1.ClearSelection();
        int deviceNameColIndex = dataGridView1.Columns["cDeviceName"].Index;
        int deviceNameColIndex2 = dataGridView1.Columns["cDeviceName2"].Index;
        int driverVerColIndex = dataGridView1.Columns["cDriverVersion"].Index;
        int driverVerColIndex2 = dataGridView1.Columns["cDriverVersion2"].Index;
        int driverProviderName = dataGridView1.Columns["cdriverProviderName"].Index;
        int driverProviderName2 = dataGridView1.Columns["cdriverProviderName2"].Index;

        try
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
            {

                rowcnt++;

                if (row.Cells[driverVerColIndex].Value.ToString() != row.Cells[driverVerColIndex2].Value.ToString() ||
                    row.Cells[driverProviderName].Value.ToString() != row.Cells[driverProviderName2].Value.ToString() ||
                    row.Cells[deviceNameColIndex].Value.ToString() != row.Cells[deviceNameColIndex2].Value.ToString()
                    )
                {
                    dataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = Color.YellowGreen;
                    row.Selected = true;
                }

            }
        }

        catch (NullReferenceException) { }
 }
```

```
How do I skip null cells?
```

Comment: For any cell in the grid, you should check to make sure the cells `Value` is NOT `null` BEFORE you try and call its `ToString` method. All the lines…`row.Cells[xxx].Value.ToString()` … assume the cells `Value` is not `null` and apparently one or more is `null` and is throwing the null reference exception. You should “check” to make sure `Value` is NOT `null` like… `if (row.Cells[driverVerColIndex].Value != null) {…}`…BEFORE you call it’s `ToString` method. Example, If the grids `AllowUsersToAddRows` property is `true`… then the cells in the “new” row will be `null.`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I meant no offense with my comment. I was just trying to nudge you to a better solution. Whether or not you choose to attempt to find a better solution is up to you. In defense of my comment, specifically in reference to the undesired side effects the `foreach` loop through the columns was creating... I was simply trying to point out “why” that approach would create some undesired/unexpected results. Please forgive me if it came across as something other than a helpful comment.

Using the current posted example, below is one possible “better” approach when trying to avoid the null reference exception specifically when looping through a `DataGridView.`

For starters, when looping through the rows in a grid and checking cell values, there is “always” the possibility that a cells value may be `null.` In some cases you “may” assume that the cells value is not `null,` however, even in those rare cases, as a coder, if the cell is “somehow” `null` and the code does not check for this… then the code crashes. The consequences are too high to ignore this check.

Therefore, when looping through the grid’s cells... it is wise to check for these `null` values before we try to call its `ToString` method.

One place to check for `null` values is if the row is the grids “new” row. If the grid’s `AllowUsersToAddRows` property is set to `true` AND the grids data source allows new rows, then you are guaranteed that the cells in that row are null. Therefore, when looping through the rows, checking for this new row will eliminate the need to check the cells. We know they are all `null` so we can “skip” that row.

You may consider simply changing the grids `AllowUserToAddRows` property to `false` and skip this check, however, what if at a later date, that property gets changed to `true`? If we “always” check for this “new” row, whether it exist or not, will allow the code to work regardless of what the `AllowUserToAddRows` property is to.

So, the first check in the `foreach` loop through the rows would be this check for the new row…

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows) {
  if (!row.IsNewRow) { … //this row it NOT the new row … }
```

This eliminates the “new” row; however, we still need to check each cell. In this case, the code would have to check the six (6) `Cell.Value`’s for `null` THEN the code would then need to compare the six (6) values two at a time. Using a bunch of `if` statements could get messy.

So, it may help if we create a method that checks two cell values and returns `true` if the cell values are equal and `false` if they are not equal. This should reduce the number of `if` statements we need. This method may look something like…

```
private bool CellsAreEqual(DataGridViewCell cell1, DataGridViewCell cell2) {
  if (cell1.Value == null && cell2.Value == null) {
    return false;
  }
  if (cell1.Value != null && cell2.Value != null) {
    return cell1.Value.ToString().Equals(cell2.Value.ToString());
  }
  else {
    // one cell is null the other cell is not null
    return false;
  }
```

The codes logic assumes that if one or both cells are `null`, then, the cells are NOT equal. First a check is made to see if both cells are `null` and if so, returns `false.` If one cell is `null` and the other cell is not `null`, then return `false`, otherwise we can safely call each `Cell.Value.ToString` method.

Finally, with the above method and the new row info, we can change the `highlightrow` method to something like…

```
private void highlightrow() {
  dataGridView1.ClearSelection();
  foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows) {
    if (!row.IsNewRow) {
      if (!CellsAreEqual(row.Cells["cDriverVersion"], row.Cells["cDriverVersion2"]) ||
          !CellsAreEqual(row.Cells["cdriverProviderName"], row.Cells["cdriverProviderName2"]) ||
          !CellsAreEqual(row.Cells["cDeviceName"], row.Cells["cDeviceName2"])) {
        dataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = Color.YellowGreen;
        row.Selected = true;
      }
    }
    else {
      // ignore new row
    }
  }
}
```

I hope this makes sense.

Comment: Firstly no offence taken at all! I knew there was a better solution somewhere to be found. Secondly, thank you for your in-depth explanation and examples. These work perfectly and I have replaced the code I had with this solution. I agree this is much better. Many thanks for your effort here.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the ideas. I have tried checking for null before but was still having issues so was looking for some practical examples. As it happens, I have managed to sort it, though still feel this could be done better:

```
private void highlightrow()
{
    int rowcnt = 0;
    dataGridView1.ClearSelection();
    int deviceNameColIndex = dataGridView1.Columns["cDeviceName"].Index;
    int deviceNameColIndex2 = dataGridView1.Columns["cDeviceName2"].Index;
    int driverVerColIndex = dataGridView1.Columns["cDriverVersion"].Index;
    int driverVerColIndex2 = dataGridView1.Columns["cDriverVersion2"].Index;
    int driverProviderName = dataGridView1.Columns["cdriverProviderName"].Index;
    int driverProviderName2 = dataGridView1.Columns["cdriverProviderName2"].Index;

    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
    {
        rowcnt++;

        foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
        {
            string val = cell.Value as string;
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(val))
            { }
            else
            {
                try
                {
                    if (
                    row.Cells[driverVerColIndex].Value.ToString() != row.Cells[driverVerColIndex2].Value.ToString() ||
                    row.Cells[driverProviderName].Value.ToString() != row.Cells[driverProviderName2].Value.ToString() ||
                    row.Cells[deviceNameColIndex].Value.ToString() != row.Cells[deviceNameColIndex2].Value.ToString()
                    )
                    {
                        dataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = Color.YellowGreen;
                        row.Selected = true;
                    }
                }
                catch { }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: The added loop through the columns may well catch a cell’s `null` value, however, if the cells are not `null` then the code will execute the `if` statement comparing the different cells at least six (6) times for every row when it only needs to execute once for each row? Are you sure this is a good solution?

Comment: In addition, the code will still fail and throw a null exception if one or more cells in a row are `null` AND one or more cells in that same row are NOT `null.` In other words, the code will only work and not throw an exception… if ALL the cells in a row are `null` or ALL the cells in a row are NOT `null.` Any other case will throw a null exception.

Comment: I'm absolutely not saying it's a good solution and think there is probably a far better solution out there! Exception may be being thrown (haven't actually tested this yet) but  the highlight function is working to the end which it wasn't before. I'm open to better suggestions by all means (prob not hard!).